# Retrieve share analytics via Linkedin API Request

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to get the metrics for organic posts [with this request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/share-statistics?view=li-lms-2022-12&tabs=http#retrieve-statistics-for-specific-shares):

```
https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A24445&ugcPosts[0]=urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A7008096555
```

But I got this error:

```
"serviceErrorCode": 100,
"code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
"message": "Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/ugcPosts[0]]"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Just for clarification: I assume that you have all the right credentials, generally speaking have the API working (the request above works if you leave out the "share" URL parameter - just does not give the values you want). I assume so, because that's where I'm standing right now with my API call (same as yours, just with different IDs) and I get exactly the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Updated Answer

I got an answer back from LinkedIn's support that did at least put me on the right track as it seems: They asked me to check for the correct headers on my request. As it turns out, the organizationalEntityShareStatistics call **does not like to be called with the "X-Restli-Protocol-Version" HTTP Header**  when having "shares" in the request.

As usual the developer documentation never tells you when to set which header and when not - and the whole "having multiple versions of the API versioning" does not help either...

For me this is a request that works:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A<org-id>&shares[0]=urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A<share-id>
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
LinkedIn-Version: 202211
```

Make sure that the URNs in the query string are urlencoded (`urn%3Ali%3A...`). For the parameter names (`shares[0]`) you can use either encoded or unencoded - both will work.

Just make sure to **not** set the `X-Restli-Protocol-Version` header

---

### Original Answer

Note that **the following is only a short term temporary workaround** because the unversioned API has been deprecated and [will be sunset at the end of February 2023](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/versioning?view=li-lms-2022-12#whats-changing) - but as of today you can still use the old API call:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A24445&shares%5B0%5D=urn%3Ali%3AugcPost%3A7008096555
```

Other changes you have to do:

- note that there is "/v2/" instead of "/rest/" in the URL
- don't set the `LinkedIn-Version` request header
- don't set the `X-Restli-Protocol-Version` request header
- if you want to query a specific time range the syntax for the new "versioned" API would look like this `timeIntervals=(timeGranularityType:DAY,timeRange:(start:1667257200000,end:1673297200000))`, but with the old API version the time range has to go to three separate query parameters like this `timeIntervals.timeGranularityType=DAY&timeIntervals.timeRange.start=1667257200000&timeIntervals.timeRange.end=1673297200000`

I will update this answer as soon as I figure out what I have to do to get the new API version working. So far I get exactly the same ACCESS_DENIED error message that you see.

Comment: @eliran Just be aware that it will only work until the end of February. I'm currently in contact with LinkedIn's Developer Support to get this sorted.

Comment: why don't get data for the posts in 2021 and back with a specific time range? (range by timestamp for the whole year), when I removed the time range parameter I get the total data..

Comment: @eliran According to the documentation "The organizationalEntityShareStatistics endpoint returns share data only within the past 12 months, using a rolling 12-month window." - And 2021 is not in the 12 month window anymore.

Comment: This was fantastic and helped me solve my migration problem on moving to new API versions. I couldn't find any documentation of this on LinkedIn's end (in fact they still claim that header is required on *all* requests). Did you find any others that this had to be excluded from? Currently I've set this up as a special case as none of the others seem to require it to be removed.

Comment: @TheCoder: So far organizationalEntityShareStatistics is the only function that I'm calling without the Restli Protocol Version header, but the API is changing so much that I wouldn't be surprised if that changes in the near future.